# Laravel-Global scope trait not being hit

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I can't seem to find the problem here. I'm using a trait to attach a global scope to all Eloquent queries on a model. Here is my model

```
<?php namespace App;

 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
 use App\Club\traits\restrictToClubTrait;


class Product extends Model
{



public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\ProductCategory', 'product_category_id', 'id');
}


public function producer()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Producer', 'producer_id');
}
}
```

And here is the trait

```
<?php namespace App\Club\traits;

trait restrictToClubTrait
{

/**
 * Boot the soft deleting trait for a model.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public static function bootRestrictToClubTrait()
{
    dd('p');
    static::addGlobalScope(new RestrictToClubScope);
}

}
```

That dd never gets hit, so the function must not be getting hit, I've poured over the docs but I don't see where I've gone wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Traits should be "included" inside the class body. For more info [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php)

```
use App\Club\traits\restrictToClubTrait;

class Product extends Model {
    use restrictToClubTrait;
}
```

Comment: dang, I knew it was going to be something simple. Thank you Sir, I'll mark correct as soon as I'm allowed.